# How does google fade out content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When you go from one page of results to the other you can see that google dims out of the current results so they are only half opaque until the new ones are loaded. Can anyone tell me how I could do this with Jquery? I would rather do it without the use of PNG's. I also want it ot go to the top of the page when the ajax is completed.

I know nothing about Jquery but this is my guess:

```
ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#contents").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
 });
ajaxStop(function(){
  $("#contents").fadeTo("fast", 1).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);;
 });
```

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. Give it a shot on your page and see if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do the fading. You will need to edit this to include your ajax code.

http://jsfiddle.net/HPdvg/1/

Hope that helps. :)